# loading two images on canvas (Java )

Tags: canvas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n0YM.png)

please,tell me what isn't correct here and how to solve such problem
Notice that I'm a beginner at learning java and all tools I can use are constructors,methods.

public class Lab03
{

```
public void loadAnImage() 
{
    // Please write your code after this line

    ColorImage car = new ColorImage();
    ColorImage car1= new ColorImage();
    ColorImage car2= new ColorImage();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(car2.getWidth(),car2.getHeight());
    car2 = car.add(car1);
    canvas.add(car);
    canvas.add(car1);








}
```

Comment: Posting code as an image is frowned upon in SO, it doesn't allow people to copy and paste the code for determining what the problems is. I would suggest that you edit your question by including the actual code.

Comment: Edited!...Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQP3i.png)

Maybe I couldn't explain the problem well..
 the problem was that I wanted to combine 2 photos into one canvas which have the same dimensions...they should be stuck to each other with no space
After many attempts,I managed to solve the problem with this code.

```
 public class Lab03{
public void loadTwoImagesOnTheSameCanvas()
{

ColorImage car = new ColorImage();
ColorImage car1 = new ColorImage();
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(2*car.getWidth(),car.getHeight());

       canvas.add(car,0,0);
       canvas.add(car1,400,0);




  }
 }
```